# Texlive copy-paste with tabs formating

Tags: latex, copy-paste, tex-live

I have a problem with texlive, when I try to copy paste some code, it pastes without tabs(formatting) in the beginning of lines. It is really annoying to type them again. Is the way to change that behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you doing that on? Have you tried copying to another text editor first and then copy from that editor to TeXLive?

Comment: I am using Linux. If I paste to/from other editor all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Setting Indentation mode to "Keep Indentation" in Option/Configure TexLive/Editor helps me.